# Create Folder in List Definition with Elements.xml

Tags: elements-xml

I am creating list definitions.Now what I want to create some folder when We create Elements.xml for list definition.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the following code in Elements.xml to create folder in list.

```
<Data>
           <Rows>
        <Row>
          <Field Name="ContentTypeId">0x0120004F994A3C0FF76546A528DA0D4B515898</Field>
          <Field Name="FileLeafRef">MyTestFolder</Field>
          <Field Name="Title">MyTestFolder</Field>
          <Field Name="FSObjType">1</Field>
        </Row>
      </Rows>
    </Data>
```

Refer to following articles for more information

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms478860(v=office.14).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-IN/library/ms478860%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

http://johnlearnt.blogspot.in/2012/09/provision-folder-inside-document-library.html

Also, you can do it from an event receiver when the list is created:

Create an event receiver (ListAdded) for the library definition (Dev Center).
Add code to create the folder structure.

SPList list = web.Lists.TryGetList("ListTitle");

SPFolderCollection folderColl = list.RootFolder.SubFolders;

SPFolder newFolder = folderColl.Add(FolderUrl);